# Probability of Two Students NOT Sitting Next to Eachother.

Tags: probability

If there were 10 desks in a row, what would be the porbability of student A and student B NOT sitting next to each other?

I figured out there's a 1/2 chance that they would sit next to each other, since there are 10 spaces and 5 pairs are within 10 desks. But is this also symmetric if they NOT sit next to each other? In other words do they have the same chances of not sitting next to each other than sitting next to each other? Because there are 10 seats and if one is sat in any of the 10, the other just has to not occupy the seat next to that person.

Comment: Seat the eight people in 8! Ways. Choose two of the gaps from the nine gaps, including one before the first and one after the last in $\binom{9}{2}$ ways. In the two places chosen, we can seat them in 2 ways. The probability is $2\times 8!\binom{9}{2}/10!= 4/5$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have 10 desks in a row. Place student A at one of the 10 desks, then place student B at one of the remaining 9 desks. Because the two students are distinct, there are 90 possible placements. We can assume that each of these are equally likely. Numbering the desks 1 to 10, the students would be sitting next to each other if they are at desks 1 & 2, 2 & 3, ect. all the way up to 9 & 10. This means that there are 9 pairs of desks that fit the criteria. For each pair of desks, there are 2 ways of arrangements the students in this pair of desks. This means that of the 90 placements, 18 put both students next to each other. This results in a $\frac{18}{90}=\frac{1}{5}$ chance of the students sitting next to each other and a $\frac{4}{5}$ chance of them sitting apart.

You can also look at this in terms of probability. When placing student A, there is an $\frac{2}{10}$ chance of choosing the 1st or 10th desk. in either case, there is only 1 adjacent desk so there is a $\frac{1}{9}$ chance of placing student B there. Meanwhile, there is a $\frac{8}{10}$ of placing student A in one of the other desks, and a $\frac{2}{9}$ chance of placing student B there since each central desk has 2 neighbors. The total probability is then:

$$(A\ in\ 1\  or\ 10)\times(B\ in\ adjacent\ seat)+(A\ in\ 2\ through\ 9)\times(B\ in\ adjacent\ seat)$$

$$=\frac{2}{10}\times\frac{1}{9}+\frac{8}{10}\times\frac{2}{9}=\frac{1}{5}$$

Since not placing them together is the only other possibility, the probability is $\frac{4}{5}$.